# Check if all buttons are selected

Tags: if-statement, selecteditem, jtogglebutton

So I have a custom button that once you select it you can't un-select it. I want to check if 6 buttons on my program are selected and do something after that. Looks messy but I thought that would have worked for me. Suggestions please?

```
  if(bomb28.getModel().isPressed()){

    if(bomb37.getModel().isPressed()){
      if(bomb16.getModel().isPressed()){
        if(bomb17.getModel().isPressed()){
            if(bomb1.getModel().isPressed()){
            if(bomb3.getModel().isPressed()){

        jLabel3.setEnabled(true);
         jLabel3.setVisible(true);
        jLabel3.setText("YOU HAVE WON");
            }
            }

    }

    }  


    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<BombButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
buttons.add(bomb28);
buttons.add(bomb32);
// etc

private boolean areButtonsDown() {
   for( BombButton button : buttons ) {
      if( !button.getModel().isPressed() ) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```